# How do I return a variable instead of a string?

Tags: php, laravel

In this example, the function validateJsonNotEmptyImage does not work as expected?

Just to clarify.

```
'src' => $image->src, // WORKS
'height' => $this->validateJsonNotEmptyImage('type', 'width'), // DOES NOT WORK
```

```
public function validateJsonNotEmptyImage($type, $array1) {
    if ($type, $array1) {
        if (isset($type->$array1)) {
            return $type . '->' . $array1;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
$productsImagesToSiteArray = array();
    foreach ($this->resource->images as $image) {
        $productsImagesToSiteArray[] = array(
            'height' => $this->validateJsonNotEmptyImage('$image', 'width'),
            'src'    => $image->src,
        );
    }
```

Comment: your should remove single quote on `$image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two mistakes

1) your method `validateJsonNotEmptyImage`, in body you have wrong IF it should be check with null[here1] and you should return value not string[here2].
And also you should return everytime any value or null[here3].

```
public function validateJsonNotEmptyImage($type, $array1) {
    if ($type != null && $array1 != null) {            <----------- here1
        if (isset($type->$array1)) {
            return $type->$array1;                     <----------- here2
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;                                       <----------- here3
 }
```

2) you should pass variable not string in your call (remove quotes from $image)

```
$this->validateJsonNotEmptyImage($image, 'width')
```